# Cannot bootstrap due to ""precise" images in RegionOne with arches [amd64 i386]" error

Tags: juju, maas, openstack

I am having an issue with installing Juju and bootstrapping. I have the Swift storage setup, and the new bucket gets created. The tools have been synced, and all that looks fine.

However when I attempt to bootstrap I get the error: "Cannot start bootstrap instance: no "precise images in RegionOne with arches."

In another bucket [Glance] I do have the Percise AMD64 image within it. I've even added the line for the "public bucket url." However, juju is still having this same issue.

Error:

```
juju -v bootstrap
2013-07-31 22:08:05 INFO juju provider.go:115 environs/openstack: opening environment "openstack"
2013-07-31 22:08:06 INFO juju provider.go:417 environs/openstack: bootstrapping environment "openstack"
2013-07-31 22:08:16 INFO juju tools.go:26 environs: reading tools with major version 1
2013-07-31 22:08:16 INFO juju tools.go:53 environs: filtering tools by series: precise
2013-07-31 22:08:16 INFO juju tools.go:76 environs: picked newest version: 1.10.0
2013-07-31 22:08:28 ERROR juju supercommand.go:235 command failed: cannot start bootstrap instance: no "precise" images in RegionOne with arches [amd64 i386]
error: cannot start bootstrap instance: no "precise" images in RegionOne with arches [amd64 i386]
```

The version that I am using is: 1.11.4-raring-amd64

My entire environments file is: [I removed all of the bits about MAAS, Amazon, and local]

```
default: openstack

environments:
  openstack:
    type: openstack
    admin-secret: f[...]2
    control-bucket: juj[..]2a
    auth-url: http://127.0.0.1:5000/v2.0/
    # default-series: precise
    auth-mode: userpass
    username: admin
    password: [XXXX]
    tenant-name: admin
    region: RegionOne
    public-bucket-url: https://swift.canonistack.canonical.com/v1/AUTH_526ad877f3e3464589dc1145dfeaac60
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to create a simplestreams file for your cloud. The simplest way for now is to use the juju image-metadata command.

Depending on your version of juju-core, it will be `juju image-metadata` or `juju-metadata generate-image`. The parameters are the same and I hope they are self explanatory. You can source your `openrc.sh` file before running it and it will take most parameters from the environment.

You need to have an image already uploaded into your cloud. See the output of the `glance list` command and pick a **precise 64bits** image.

The metadata command will give you two files: index.json and imagemetadata.json. You need to upload these to a bucket called juju-dist, and a path called streams/v1. Like this:

First, create the bucket:

```
swift post juju-dist
```

Now give it the proper ACLs:

```
swift post juju-dist -r '.r:*'
```

And now upload the generated files:

```
swift upload juju-dist/streams/v1 imagemetadata.json index.json
```

Now point your `public-bucket-uri` config parameter from your environments.yaml file to your object storage url. To find it, run `keystone catalog` and look for the `publicURL` address inthe `Service: object-store` block. That's what you will put in your juju `public-bucket-url` config parameter.

Now you should be able to bootstrap juju with a precise 64bit image (use `series: precise` in your `environments.yaml` file), assuming you have taken care of the tools.

More information:

- https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/juju-dev/2013-August/001324.html

Comment: It seems some people are missing the juju-generate command, I have posted a query here: https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/juju/2013-August/002814.html

Comment: I'm still getting the same error message, despite:
public-bucket-url: http://127.0.0.1:8080/v1/AUTH_3[....]4e
and the metadata being in the juju-dist bucket.

Is there away to confirm that it is looking in that bucket?

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure that you have installed the `python-glanceclient` packet. Otherwise, `juju` can't find the images.